# How to use option(error = ) with a custom function and still make the script abort (in R)

Tags: r, error-handling

Can anyone point me to the best way to use `option(error = function(...){})` properly? I want to write errors to a log file and then terminate as usually. Currently I use

```
  options(error = function(...) {
    #... write to logfile ...
    options(error = NULL)
    stop(geterrmessage())
  })
```

But resetting the option and calling `stop()` again looks like a hack to me. I also tried `q("no", status = 1, runLast = FALSE)` (as from the documentation of `stop()`), but this does not seem to be equivalent to a normal `stop()`. For example, in RStudio server it quits the whole session.

I need to use the `option()` instead of `tryCatch()` because I want to catch all possible errors that occur in the script. I launch my script via a cron job, and I want to get an email/log entry as soon as the script fails.

Answer (score 0):

A `tryCatch` block would probably be the best option for this type of situation.

```
tryCatch({
  #... main code to run ...

}, warning = function(w) {
  #... code to run if any warnings occur ...
  warning(w) # Show the warning

}, error = function(e) {
  #... write to log file ...
  stop(e) # Stop script and show error message. Delete this line if you do not want to stop script

}, finally = {
  #... code to run whether or not error occurs ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I know about tryCatch, but I really need to set the error handler for the whole script (I'll add some clarifcation to my original question). I want all errors caught, not just the ones I can expect. I guess I could just wrap the whole script in a tryCatch block, but that's even less nice than my current Solution.